# Grouping in Elastic Search using unique keys

Tags: elasticsearch, key, unique, grouping

I have a corpus of documents that can be described as follows:

```
itemId1, {userid1, userid2, userid3}, sometext1
itemId1, {userid1, userid2, userid3}, sometext2
itemId1, {userid1, userid2, userid3}, sometext3
itemId1, {userid1, userid2, userid3}, sometext4
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext6
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext7
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext8
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext9
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext10
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext11
```

Every document has a ES timestamp as well. Using ES i'd like to get a list of items for a given userId with only the latest itemId present in the result.

For example, the result for userid1 must only return the following two results:

```
itemId1, {userid1, userid2, userid3}, sometext4
itemId2, {userid1, userid3, userid4}, sometext11
```

given that `sometext4` and `sometext11` are the latest entries for `itemId1` and `itemId2` respectively based on timestamp.

Currently I'm doing a query just using the `userId` as filter and then post-processing the results in code. However this requires always fetching a pretty large search result without need and I was wondering if there is a way to do it completely (or at least mostly) in ES without any post-processing necessary.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Update**

The only approximation so far I've found is :

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "streamId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "itemId1",
        "order": {
          "time": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "time": {
          "max": {
            "field": "_timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you only the itemId and timestamp but not the full documents unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This could *probably* be done with a feature called grouping/field collapsing. 
Sadly, this feature hasn't yet landed in Elasticsearch, see: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256

afaik, there's no other way to do this.